# Android multiple screen size support

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, android-screen-support

I have made layouts for the following screens:

> 2.7' QVGA
>
> 3.2' HVGA
>
> 5.1' WVGA
>
> 3.7' Nexus One

Now I want to make layout screens for 540px X 960 px, 720px X 1280px, 480 X 854,
but I can not find any way to make it.
What is exactly way to support all the size of phones and tablets?

Comment: use different layouts and drawables folder.

Comment: ok so if I make layouts like : layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge Also if I made drawables in hdpi,mdpi,ldpi and xhdpi. Then will it support all screens?

Comment: yes it will work fine. I recommend you to look at your "/android-sdk/platforms/android-10/data/res" folder for reference how they are maintaining the layout and drawable.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out the dimensions of the screen dynamically

```
Display mDisplay= activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width= mDisplay.getWidth();
int Height= mDisplay.getHeight();
```

The layout can be set using the width and the height obtained using this method.